# Bash script works properly, but not by cron

Tags: bash, cron

I wrote a small script, which checks exit code status of program, and perform actions depending on which exit code status it got.
The script works perfectly if to run it from command line, but when trying to run it via cron job, it runs always by cron, despite of program works or not. Such feeling that it ignores exit status tests.
Normal exit status of working program is always zero. If program doesn't respond, we get rc > 1.
As a result, the program is restarted everytime when cron runs it (I see it in logs and by process "uptime").
Cron job looks like this:

```
*/5 * * * * root /root/scripts/check.sh
```

Here is my script. I expect restart only if exit code of $check_cmd is not equal to zero.

```
#!/bin/sh

check_cmd="omreport chassis memory"
srvadmin_path="/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin/srvadmin-services.sh"

if [ -x $srvadmin_path ]; then
    $check_cmd > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then

### Clear semaphores before restart the program ###
        for i in $(ipcs -st | grep -v oracle | awk '(NR>3)' |cut -d ' ' -f 1)
            do ipcrm -s $i; done && $srvadmin_path restart &&\
            systemctl restart nrpe && logger -t omsa -p local0.info "Restart OMSA due to an error"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.". You never need grep and/or cut when you're using awk btw, `grep -v oracle | awk '(NR>3)' |cut -d ' ' -f 1` is probably equivalent to `awk '!/oracle/ && (++cnt > 3){print $1}'` depending on the output of `ipcs -st`.

Comment: Which file contains your cronjob `*/5 * * * * root /root/scripts/check.sh` and which OS/distribution do you use?

Comment: There's no need to use all of `grep`, `awk`, and `cut`. Combine them into `awk '!/oracle/ && NR > 3 { print $1 }'`

Comment: Redirect output of the script to a file. `/root/scripts/check.sh >check.out 2>&1`. Then check the file.

Comment: @Cyrus, my cron job is in the file /etc/cron.d/omcheck

Comment: Thanks all, I will try in a while and let you know...

Comment: Specify the full path to each utility you run (`omreport`, `ipcrm`...) or set PATH appropriately.

Comment: cron jobs run with a really minimal environment, including only a very basic `PATH`. My guess is that `omreport`, `ipcs`, `ipcrm`, etc are in directories that aren't included in that `PATH`, so you're getting command not found errors (Barmar's suggestion to capture output & errors should show this). See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/784252/crontab-and-binaries-in-usr-local-bin/785102#785102).

Comment: Some people put `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the top of their crontab.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info . Good luck.

Comment: See [CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22743548/4154375), [Bash script runs manually, but fails on crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14612444/4154375), and [Script not producing correct output when run from cron](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76980833/4154375).

Comment: Everybody thankful for the help, the problem is solved now. The problem was with path to binary. Looks like when cron executed test program, it could not find it, and got error, that's why full script started all the time. Thanks for nice awk snippets by the way =)